# bash check if the outputs (.txts) in multiple directories contained certain string

Tags: linux, bash

I generated multiple script.txt in multiple directories for different subjects. Now I need to check if all the script.txts contain string " finished without error". If yes, returned ok; if no, returned parents directory, so that I knew which subject went wrong.

```
for i in *
do
    if grep "$finished without error" $i; then
        echo "ok"
    else
        echo $parentdir
    fi
done
```

It was fine when I checked in subdirectories where I stored the text file. However, when I directed to main directory of subjects, it gave me error.

Comment: Can you please attach the error message you are getting?

Comment: Before your next question, take the [tour], read [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for i in *` will only process the files under the directory where your script is called from.  It will not go down directories recursively.

If you want to process the current directory, and all sub-directories, you should use `find` to do such a task.  Like this:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -L "finished without error" {} \;
```

This will return a list of all files that do not contain `finished without error`.

Details:

- `find .`: will run the find on the current directory (`.`)
- `-type f`: will only perform the action on files.  Directories are traversed, but the grep will not be attempted on those.
- `-exec SOMETHING \;`:  will execute SOMETHING for each file that matches the `find` condition.  Here the only one is `-type f`.  So it will execute SOMETHING for each file.  `\;` is to let `find` that the arguments to `-exec` are complete.
- Here SOMETHING is: `grep -L "finished without error" {}`.  `-L` of `grep` lists the filename if the search does not find what you searched for.  `{}` tells the `find` command to execute the `grep` command on the current file it found.

So it will traverse your directories, find each file and run the `grep` on each of those files.  `grep` will output the filenames that do not contain the text.

---

For your script, you can put your code in https://www.shellcheck.net/, it will let you know your syntax errors and propose solutions.  Like `$finished` should probably not have the `$` in there.  I guess it is simple text.  Unless you have a `$finished` variable defined somewhere, but in the code you put here, it is not initialized.  Same for `$parentdir`